# How to replace socket transport unix:// on Windows 7 Pro for python-based dbus-system?

Tags: python, windows, dbus, unix-socket, gdbus

I try to use this library to implement DBus on windows: https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus:

I get error: 
Unknown or non-supported transport method unix:// for address
unix:oath=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

If anyone knows straight-out-of-the-box working dbus-system for Windows, I'd be delighted :)

I'm rewriting a port of a linux-based software for windows, and the software uses DBus in the background.

Comment: Are you using the Windows port of DBus? According to the [readme](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/README.win) it uses TCP sockets. You could open an issue on the pydbus project page to request supporting DBus on Windows.

Comment: I started porting "top to down direction". I went to see DBus Windows port, but didn't get to delve into it. I'll see in a couple of days if I can make it work on my machine, when I have time to continue this.
I changed unix-sockets to use TCP sockets instead.
Maybe I should make another, new question about DBus on Windows, if I have something to ask about it? Since my question, I see, is two-parted, one is about unix-sockets, which is resolved with TCP. Other is about replacing (Linux)DBus in Windows.